# extend time range when drag external item to fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

im using fullcalendar.io javascript library.
https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.6.2/demos/external-dragging.html

on there example link, can drag and drop an external item into calendar with selected range (as you can see light blue color).

i think default selected range was 2 hours. so can I change that range per each external items differently?

please reply me even if couldn't understand a question.

thanks

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/droppable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, you can specify this as a data attribute on the draggable object. For instance:

```
$('.draggable').data('duration', '03:00');
```

would set a default duration of 3 hours on all elements with the class "draggable". You can also set it as an attribute in the markup, if that's preferable:

```
<div class="draggable" data-duration="03:00" />
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/droppable/ for more details.

Comment: perfect answer!  thank you. could you explain one more me how to specific start time for "draggable"? (ref. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/eventReceive/)

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The start time will be as per the place where the user drops the event on the calendar, surely?

Comment: yeah I know, but I just want to fix the start time per draggable item like 1st item start time is 09:00 AM. and 2st item start time is 15:00 like this.

Comment: are you always dropping it on the "month" view (where there's no specific time to drop on, just a day), or sometimes on an "agenda" type view as well? That might affect the solution

Comment: probably I should make a question for this again. but your help was so helpful to me. thank you.